# css files not loading after capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, capistrano

I have noticed that after I do a deploy via capistrano, the static css files dont seem to be loading, this is true when I specially specify

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'resume',:cache => true %>
```

removing the :cache => true solves the problem, but I would like to know why that option is causing a problem in the first case, and secondly what is the best practice while deploying the rails application via capistrano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:cache => true` creates a file called all.css if it doesn't already exist in your stylesheets directory.  It is useful when you have multiple stylesheets that you want to combine so your page will have fewer http requests.  Delete this file when you deploy a new version and it will be regenerated from the newest stylesheets.

Comment: Interesting, so this is not really a capistrano issue.